# Installing brushes in Blender 3.0

Tags: installation, brushes

I am very new to blender.  I downloaded some brushed from Poliigon and have now idea how to install them.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Poliigon has a tutorial on [Using Brushes](https://help.poliigon.com/en/articles/1712671-using-brushes-in-zbrush-blender-or-substance) (in Blender)

It says, in part:

1. Enter into Sculpt mode
2. In the toolbar (T), Add a New Texture
3. In the texture properties, click Open Image
4. Locate your alpha brush and click Open.
5. In the toolbar, change the stroke method to Anchored
6. Click and drag the brush onto your mesh, and you should see the folds appear.

EDIT:  3.0 differs starting at step 2.  Here are the changes:

2. In the properties editor go to the *Texture* tab, make sure *Brush* is selected an click *New*
3. (Optional) Give the texture a name
4. In the *Image* panel *Settings* subpanel, click open.
5. Find the image by navigating the file panel.
6. The texture should no be visible in the *Tool* tab of the sidebar. (Not toolbar.  Use <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle sidebar visibility.)
7. To save the brush, click the "Fake User" Shield.
8. Change the *Stroke Method* to anchored.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Version 3.0 is different than the video.  I think I did it correctly but still having trouble applying it.  I didn't see any way to save the brush. I will have to play around some more and see if I can get it working.